# How to generate list of map into csv?

Tags: java

How to generate list of map into csv?

I  try to get the key as headers and values as columns but, I get a list of values in the same key.

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBFsU.png)

Comment: `Stream.concat(Stream.of(Arrays.stream(columns)), maps.stream().map(m -> Arrays.stream(columns).map(m::get))).map(s -> s.map(v -> '"' + v.replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"').collect(Collectors.joining(","))).forEach(out::println);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a CSV file from a list of maps in Java, you can use a combination of the StringJoiner class and the FileWriter class.

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");

for (Map<String, String> map : listOfMaps) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        sj.add(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
}

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.csv");
fw.write(sj.toString());
fw.flush();
fw.close();
```

Comment: I am getting output as firstName=Manuel firstName=Theressa city=Wuckertmouth city=Schowalterville

Comment: can you verify this?